# elasticsearch-hadoop exception about date type mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I got the following exception, I'm very confused about this:

```
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopParsingException: 
Cannot parse value [2016-03-13T02:32:56] for field [create_time]
```

My mapping as following:

```
"mappings": {
    "users": {
        "properties": {
          "create_time": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be
`"format": "strict_date_time_no_millis"`

`date_time_no_millis` or `strict_date_time_no_millis`

> A formatter that combines a full date and time without millis,
>   separated by a T: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ. [custom-date-format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/mapping-date-format.html#custom-date-formats)

Comment: I'm confused that, the index is already there, value  is 2016-03-13T02:32:56, type is strict_date_optional_time. But when I use es-hadoop read it, it threw exception.